# VisualStudio C++ created executable not deployable on other Win10 computers (error "0xc000007b")

Tags: windows, visual-c++

When I compile a simple "Hello World" C++ program with VisualStudio (2017 community edition), the executable runs on the devolopment computer with Windows 10, but on a different computer with the same OS and architecture, the program fails to start with an error "0xc000007b" ("Application was unable to start correctly").

Does someone have suggestions what I could try out to create a portable executable with VisualStudio? It seems to be a common problem with VisualStudio, but I have not found anything useful on the web for solving it.

Here is the C++ code of my program:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Program started", "Message", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the used set of compile options according to VisualStudio (*Release* mode for *x64*):

```
/GS /TP /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"D:\test\build" /I"D:\test"
/I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" /Gm- /O2 /Ob2
/Fd"test1.dir\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "_WINDOWS"
/D "_VARIADIC_MAX=10" /D "NOMINMAX" /D "NDEBUG" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\""
/D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /Oy /MD /Fa"Release/"
/EHsc /nologo /Fo"test1.dir\Release\" /Ot /Fp"test1.dir\Release\test1.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

And this is the list of libraries linked into the executable as reported by *dumpbin*:

```
D:\test\build\Release>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\dumpbin.exe" /DEPENDENTS test1.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.16.27032.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file test1.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    USER32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    KERNEL32.dll

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        1000 .text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the appropriate **Visual C++ Redistributable** on the target computer.

[Redistributable for Visual C++ 2015, 2017, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

On your development computer this is already installed with Visual Studio.

Comment: I did not mention it, but I have packaged the `VCRUNTIME140.dll` with the executable. The problem is not missing DLLs, but that the executable cannot be loaded by the OS. Moreover, there must be a way to create an isntaller for VC creatded binaries that does not require the user to seperately install VC-Runtimes on the target computer.

Comment: It's possible that some DLL libraries are loaded only at runtime. You could see this in Visual Studio in the "Modules" window while debugging. Or you use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) (**x64**) and "Profile". Most installers provide the possibility to install redistributable along, when not available on the target computer (e.g. [here with WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html) )

Comment: Just had the opportunity to test it on the target computer, and installing the "Redistributable" package indeed solves the issue. Thank you very much!